# What is the benefit of using the HTML5 <time> tag?

Tags: usability, accessibility, dates, browser, html5

I have a web application I am writing the HTML for.  In the app I will be displaying a lot of dates and in HTML5 they added a [`<time>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time).  If I wrap all of my dates and times in the `<time>` tag what will be the end result for the user?  Do any browsers style it different?  Are there any screen readers or plugins which will interact with it?  I know it is supposed to make the dates easily machine readable, but what is the computer going to do with it?  I am not really sure what benefit this will have to the user experience and the usability/accessibility of the site.

UPDATE: I checked [gCal](https://calendar.google.com) and it is not using the `<time>` tag anywhere. Does this mean it is not worth the time and money making the back-end code automatically wrap all dates/time in this tag?

Answer (score 6):

The time element is a **machine-readable** element. So it is mainly used to help out the computer not the user *directly*.

https://css-tricks.com/time-element/

> The  element in HTML represents a machine-readable date, time, or duration. It can be useful for creating event scheduling, archiving, and other time-based functions.

and

> The uses of unambiguous dates in web pages aren’t hard to imagine. A browser could offer to add events to a user’s calendar. A Thai-localised browser could offer to transform Gregorian dates into Thai Buddhist era dates. A Japanese browser could localise 16:00 to "16:00時". Content aggregators can produce visual timelines of events.
>
> Search engines can produce smarter search results. **...**

Comment: exactly. Also, to add to the answer since it's part of the question, it doesn't render differently (so the user won't notice anyhting), BUT you can make it render as you wish by simply styling the `time` tag, so it's a semantic way to modify styles as well

Comment: @Devin I wanted to say something like that but then I wondered if this tag is what highlights/"makes into links" times and dates on mobile phones, hence making it display a bit differently. [Like this](http://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/image-jpg.443231/)

Comment: not necessarily. I have seen this behavior even without the ´time´ tag, so mobile browsers tend to detect it in some way. However, it's true that having the tag would allow you to style as you wish rather than leaving to pure browser rendering.

Comment: In the answer above it talk about what a browser **could** do.  Is there any concrete evidence that the browser or search engines actually do anything with it?  I know I could style it but I could do the same thing with a class.

Comment: I don't want to invade @DasBeasto 's great answer, but yes. He even implies it in the comment and provided link, browsers and apps READ your `time` tag and users can add it to calendars automatically. Just a small example. And obviously, a `semantic html5 tag` is way beyond a class, but it will take more than a comment to explain it all. Let's simplify at *"a class is for styling, not for content"* . A very in-depth discussion with examples can be found at https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Time_element

Comment: @Devin Thank you that is a very helpful (and extensive) link. 

Eric It is certainly easier to find concrete evidence for application level use (i.e. the Reddit example in my link in the answer). As for browsers/search engines it is much more difficult/impossible because we don't really know whats going on inside say Google's search algorithm. However, as a standardized machine readable date element I find it hard to imagine Google would not take it into account.

Comment: Another example usage is that is helps scrapers like [my article reading extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-read/dgmanlpmmkibanfdgjocnabmcaclkmod) to find the correct date